# Typescript and GraphQL mismatch types between graphql response and typescript type

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am using `typescript`, `react-apollo` and `AWS Appsync` for a react app I am building, but running into typescript warnings which I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

I have a graphql schema that looks like -

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    events: [Event]
}

type Event {
   ...
}
```

I am using `useQuery` to return all events, like -

```
const {
   loading: eventsListLoading,
   error: eventsListError,
   data: eventsListData
} = useQuery(EVENTS_LIST_HOME);
```

EVENTS_LIST_HOME comes from -

```
export const EVENTS_LIST_HOME = gql`
    query eventsListHome{
        events {
            title
        }
    }
`;
```

and I am trying to render the items like -

```
<table>
   {
      eventsListData.events.map((event: IEvent) => (
         <tr>
             <td>{event.title}</td>
         </tr>
      ))
   }
</table>
```

where I have a typescript interface `IEvent`

```
export default interface IEvent {
    title: string;
}
```

but I am getting the error -

[image]

I have tried renaming the typescript type to `Event` instead of `IEvent` and adding the other args, index and array, even though they are not used, but same error

What am I missing? How do I use the grapghql type of `Event` in typescript?

Comment: How do you generate your typescript types? TypeScript has structural typing, meaning that types shapes need to be compatible - names don't matter. The easiest thing might be to simply omit the annotation. The type seems to be inferred.

Comment: @Herku I currently don't generate them. I was doing them manually. Should I be generating them? Unfortunately I wasn't getting any intellisense for `event` in my IDE when i omit the type in the `map` callback

Answer (score 2):

You should use `apollo` codegen to generate TypeScript types for the types declared in your graphql schema - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output.

It looks like there is a type mismatch between `Event` and `IEvent`. Can't say much without seeing the definition of `Event`.

Using the types generated by `apollo codegen` should fix the type errors.

Comment: i ended up using graphql-codegen (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphql-codegen/cli) in the end, thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using `apollo` cli because it's the official one and works well with `react-apollo`.